# Should I add files from an already published package to my new github project?

Tags: python, github

let's say I created a python package and published it on my github. Now I want to publish another project based on this package. Should I add the package files to the new repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: No :)

The main reason for creating a package, dependency, library, etc is to re-use it in different projects.

Try importing the package in your other project and if it doesn't work, you can share your code in another question.